# My column loop stops when I get to the double letters in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying go throught 24 columns of data and get specific info, when I get to the  AA columns, in Excel, my code stops. I don't understand why?

```
Sub Resultas_ELEC()
Dim iChar As Integer, i, j, k, l, m, n, a
a = 71     'colums searching in; 65==A, 71 == G ,    94==AD
For iChar = 71 To 94
i = Chr(iChar)
j = Chr(a)
k = Chr(a)
l = Chr(a)
m = Chr(a)
n = Chr(a)
Range(i & "77") = ActiveSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(Range(i & "7:" & i & "73"), "=S")
Range(i & "78") = ActiveSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(Range(j & "7:" & j & "73"), "=E")
Range(i & "79") = ActiveSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(Range(k & "7:" & k & "73"), "=E-S")
Range(i & "80") = ActiveSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(Range(l & "7:" & l & "73"), "=E-E")
Range(i & "81") = ActiveSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(Range(m & "7:" & m & "73"), "=E-A")
Range(i & "82") = ActiveSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(Range(n & "7:" & n & "73"), "=A")
a = a + 1
Next iChar
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Cells()` which allows the use of numeric column references.

```
Sub Resultas_ELEC()
    Dim iChar As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet 'should set this to the correct worksheet instead of relying on activesheet
    
        For iChar = 7 To 30
            .Cells(77, iChar) = ActiveSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(7, iChar), .Cells(73, iChar)), "=S")
            .Cells(78, iChar) = ActiveSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(7, iChar), .Cells(73, iChar)), "=E")
            .Cells(79, iChar) = ActiveSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(7, iChar), .Cells(73, iChar)), "=E-S")
            .Cells(80, iChar) = ActiveSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(7, iChar), .Cells(73, iChar)), "=E-E")
            .Cells(81, iChar) = ActiveSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(7, iChar), .Cells(73, iChar)), "=E-A")
            .Cells(82, iChar) = ActiveSheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(7, iChar), .Cells(73, iChar)), "=A")
        Next iChar
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou it works great! I use the activesheet because I have 23 tabs divided into 5 groups and I don't know how to call a group of sheets to apply my code to.